# Match data through User ID and return 'TRUE' OR 'FALSE'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 spreadsheets, 1 is the 'master data' sheet and the second is the 'verification' sheet (to check.

I want to match the data from the 'verification' sheet with 'the master data' sheet through User ID  to match DOB, Name, organization name, and user ID to return 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'.

The screenshot is attached for reference.

MasterSheet
[image: Sheet 1]

Verification Sheet 2
[image: Sheet 2]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDEX/MATCH` functions combination.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$E$4,MATCH($B9,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(G$8,$A$1:$E$1,0))=INDEX($B$9:$E$11,MATCH($B9,$B$9:$B$11,0),MATCH(G$8,$B$8:$E$8,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harun24hr, I used the above formula on a large dataset and I'm getting a "#N/A" error (MATCH Range must be a single row or a single column).

Comment: It seems you specifying more than one column to match function. Can you post your formula here?

Comment: =INDEX($N$2:$Q$2034,MATCH($A3,$N$2:$Q$2034,0),MATCH($F$2,$N$1:$Q$1,0))=INDEX($A$3:$D$2034,MATCH($A3,$A$3:$A$2034,0),MATCH($F$2,$A$2:$D$2,0))

Comment: This should be `=INDEX($N$2:$Q$2034,MATCH($A3,$N$2:$N$2034,0),MATCH($F$2,$N$1:$Q$1,0))=INDEX($A$3:$D$2034,MATCH($A3,$A$3:$A$2034,0),MATCH($F$2,$A$2:$D$2,0)) `

Comment: I tried the above formula and changed a few values but it is not showing FALSE, even if the data is different then also it is showing TRUE. Especially for Name and DOB

Comment: If a User ID is different then it displays "#NA" for other cells as well (though other cells contain exact match data)

Comment: @RamanSingh So, you want each cell to match. ID is not fact here, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to match each cell.

Comment: In that case, lets say you are searching for `1/14/2000` and if it exist for other user rather than `A1235` still it will show `TRUE`. But it should show `FALSE` as this user `A1235` DOB is not `1/14/2000`

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: Then, I think current formula is correct and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this in F3. Change MasterSheet with the actual name of your sheet:

```
=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A3:A),3,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(B2:D,r,c)=INDEX(FILTER({MasterSheet!B2:B,MasterSheet!E2:E,MasterSheet!D2:D},MasterSheet!A2:A=INDEX(A3:A,r)),,c)))
```

Comment: Thank you @Martín, I tried the above Formula but it is showing all the values as FALSE. Could you please guide me? The Formula I used is: =MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A2:A),3,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(B2:D,r,c)=INDEX(FILTER({Sheet8!B2:B,Sheet8!E2:E,Sheet8!D2:D},Sheet8!A2:A=INDEX(A3:A,r)),,c)))